# "File Sync error." with Ubuntu One

Tags: ubuntu-one

I cannot sync my documents to Ubuntu One. I get this message `File Sync error. (auth failed (AUTH_FAILED))` when I click on Ubuntu One from Preferences.

I have tried clearing the Ubuntu One entries in **Password and Encryption Keys** but that doesn't seem to be the problem. I am using Ubuntu 11.04 and am fairly new to Linux.

Comment: user20248: Having the same results as you. I have noticed that the Ubuntu One client does seem to pull down information on connected devices so there is network activity at some level. I have the following messages in my syncdaemon.log file: 2011-07-10 14:18:34,956 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.EQ - DEBUG - push_event: SYS_STATE_CHANGED, kwargs: {'state': AUTHENTICATE (error=False connected=True online=False) Queue: WORKING Connection: With User With Network} 2011-07-10 14:18:35,311 - ubuntuone.SyncDaemon.EQ - DEBUG - push_event: SYS_AUTH_ERROR, kwargs: {'error': 'AUTHENTICATION_FAILED'} 2011-07-10 1

Answer (score 7):

ROOT_MISMATCH in syncdaemon.log - This normally indicates that there may be two Ubuntu One accounts, one in the local cache and another setup in the keyring. This happens if the user installed Ubuntu One with one account and then sets up the computer again with a different account (but all the old Ubuntu One files in ~/.local/share/ubuntuone are still there under the old account). Working around this:

Open Applications->Accessories->Terminal and run:

```
u1sdtool -q; killall ubuntuone-login ubuntuone-preferences;
sudo rm -rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone
rm -rf ~/.cache/ubuntuone
rm -rf ~/.config/ubuntuone
mv ~/Ubuntu\ One/ ~/Ubuntu\ One_old/
```

Open Applications->Accessories->Passwords and Encryption Keys, go to the Passwords tab, delete the Ubuntu One and Desktopcouch tokens by right-clicking on them and selecting "Delete".

Back in a terminal session, run:

```
u1sdtool -q; killall ubuntuone-login; u1sdtool -c
```

---

To get things functioning again, all I had to do was delete my ~/.local/share/ubuntuone directory as indicated above. The u1sdtool line noted above did nothing for me.  I mention this just so you do not stop prematurely.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Basically worked for me though all I had to do was use u1sdtool --quit Then go in a delete all the Ubuntu One and desktop couch stuff from the passwords and keys (there were several). After this I started the Ubuntu One gui, hit the "already have account" button, entered in my login and everything re-synced fine.